# Dynamic renormalize in matplotlib after set_data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making an interactive display of 3d data in 2d via .imshow() method. I let the user to change the mode between viewing a single 2d layer and viewing the sum along all 2d layers. This results in large changes of range of the displayed values. For this reason keeping the same color mapping all the time results in the image becoming oversaturated and unreadable. I use .set_data() method of AxesImage class for changing the displayed data and I need a way of recalculating the color mapping at the same time. The closest I got to this goal is this function:

```
def blit_data(self, data):
    c_norm  = cs.Normalize(vmin=np.nanmin(data), vmax=np.nanmax(data))
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
    scalar_map = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=c_norm, cmap=cmap)
    cmapped = scalar_map.to_rgba(data)
    self.display.set_data(cmapped)

(cmx = matplotlib.cm, cs = matplotlib.colors, plt = matplotlib.pyplot)
```

However this has an unwanted side effect: mousing over a pixel in the displayed image now displays [r g b] tuple as tooltip, instead of the original float64 value, which hinders exploration of this data. For this reason I am looking for another method to achieve the same effect. A follow up question will be how to communicate this renormalization to a colorbar, so it stays relevant.

Comment: `cm.set_clim` does not work?

Comment: I don't think I understand, `cm` module doesn't have a `set_clim` metod and even if it did it would probably be global. Do you mean the `set_clim` method of `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`? And if so how would that apply here? In the code I posted I already use an instance of ScalarMappable and it introduces the issue with [r g b a] on mouseover.
Or maybe I just failed to find the `set_clim` you mean, honestly the docs are a bit messy.

Comment: Sorry, i thought cm in your code was a scalar mappable. Your self.display is a scalar mappale instance, use its set_clim

Comment: Yup, that did it, and also works with colorbar. I'm new to stackoverflow but I believe you should post an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)

im1 = ax1.imshow(data, interpolation='none', cmap='viridis')
im2 = ax2.imshow(data, interpolation='none', cmap='viridis')
im2.set_clim(0, .5)
```

[image: example output]